# Why is my callback function called last?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I'm really stuck with this  at the moment, see the code below:

```
var getImageFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
var img = new Image, data, ret={data: null, pending: true};

img.onError = function() {
    throw new Error('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
}
img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    // Grab the image as a jpeg encoded in base64, but only the data
    data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').slice('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.length);
    // Convert the data to binary form
    data = atob(data)
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);

    ret['data'] = data;
    ret['pending'] = false;
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback(data);
    }
}
img.src = url;

return ret;
}
```

and here's my call to it:

```
getImageFromUrl('pdfconversion/roundel.jpg', addImage);
```

So basically, for my method to do what I actually want it to do (that isn't shown here) I need the callback function, which in this case is 'addImage' to be called immediately after accessing the getImageFromUrl method. At the moment, the getImageFromUrl method is called and then the rest of my code (not shown above) is run before the callback function of 'addImage' is eventually invoked. How do I get this to be the very NEXT call? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by called `last`?

Comment: Removing `[java]` tag are it doesn't appear to be related.

Comment: So you want the callback to execute sequentially? It won't be a callback then.

Comment: The callback will be executed when the image has finished loading. You have no control over how long that will take.

Comment: uhm, this is expected behaviour, as your passed callback - function is invoked in the `.onload` - callback of the `image` - element, which gets fired after the image has loaded completely. That's why it's called a "callback" - function, it's supposed to fire after something else is completed. If you need the image - element in it, that's the only way to do it, if you don't, why don't you just invoke the function right in the body of `getImageFromUrl` rather than the onload-callback?

Comment: Do you understand that onload is an asynchronous action and there is no way to make that synchronous in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the callback and just call it sequentially:

```
getImageFromUrl('pdfconversion/roundel.jpg');
addImage();
```